# When to use visibility:hidden vs display:none

Tags: html, dynamic, static, visibility, display

I understand that using `visibility:hidden` preserves the space on the page and `display:none` does not, however, when does it make sense to "preserve" the space?  That can leave an awkward blank area/gaping hole in the page.

Answer (score 4):

**Display:none** - **Dynamic Pages/Sections:** use this generally for larger dynamic areas on the page to avoid leaving an awkward blank area that makes the page look bad.  When displayed it will move the other parts of the page and render itself in the page where its designed to be, altering the position and flow of the surrounding page elements as needed/designed.

**Visibility:hidden** - **Static Pages/Sections:** use this for smaller pieces where having the surrounding elements move when this piece becomes visible is **undesirable**, i.e.: showing/hiding a badge in a page section.  Using display:none could/would force itself into the section of the page and move its surrounding elements to make room for itself, resulting in movement on the page.  Using visibility:hidden in that case would hide/show the "badge" element without any movement of the rest of the surrounding page elements as that space had been "preserved/reserved" for it, therefore, it just "turns it on/off" without any visible movement.

Since this usage is on a small piece of an otherwise "static" page section the blank "hole" in the page left there because of the "preserved/reserved" space isn't noticeable when hidden because the page's "layout" doesn't depend on the small "preserved/reserved" space for the badge.  Its only a small piece within a larger static area.

Hope this helps with deciding when/where to use these two seemingly similar attributes.